# Sharepoint client API invalid DateTime field

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint list with `DateTime` field. I'm using the Silveright SharePoint client API to update this fields. When I save a value to the field, it is saved and displayed in SharePoint without problems.

But when I try to get the value, it is absolutely different (minus some time). What's wrong with it?

In SharePoint, the datetime is:

[image]

Load code:

```
clientContext.Load(contactItem, item => item[Constants.TipFields.Title],
    item => item[Constants.TipFields.Description],
    item => item[Constants.TipFields.UserDefinedDateTime],
    item => item.Id);`
```

Here I have an incorrect date:

```
var description = tipItem[Constants.TipFields.Description] as String;
var title = tipItem[Constants.TipFields.Title] as String;
var date = tipItem[Constants.TipFields.UserDefinedDateTime] as DateTime;
```

And loaded datetime is:
[image]

What's wrong here?

Comment: The value you retrieve is only 2 hours earlier than the value you see displayed in SharePoint. Is it a timezone conversion?

Comment: I dont want to convert value. What i suppose to do???

Comment: It's irrelevant what you **want** to do here. If SharePoint is storing the date as a UTC value but not converting it when you retrieve, then it's **your** job to convert it to suit your purposes.

Comment: I dont need sharepoint to convert my date time. This field indicating when server recieved value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this bug (feature in sharepoint) by using simple plain text or custom field to store specific date time not in UTC format.

Answer (score 5):

Sharepoint stores all date field in UTC. That is, if you are saving a datetime field in a list, Sharepoint actually converts the time that you selected into UTC, and converts it back to whatever time zone the person is in when retrieving.

Begin by checking if there's a difference between your server timezone and your client.